# Statistical difference between Gender

Tags: t-test

Just wanting a sounding board to test whether my idea or thinking is correct.

If I have collected data of large quantity with various field (income, age of customer etc) for the completion of a sales promotion (1 for complete and 0 for no complete), I would like to compare gender effect (or whether there is a disproportionate number of F/M in completion of the sales promotion)

I would be comparing the group mean between promotion success and failure

- by grouping success participants of Male(0) and Female(1) into success group
- by grouping failure participants of Male(0) and Female(1) into failure group
- Calculate the sum, mean and variance of each group and then perform either

  ```
      a) Welch's t-test for unequal variance
      b) independent t-test for equal variance
  ```
- and compare their mean  (assuming the distribution is normal and the sample size is large)

Regards

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user2974951: whether there is more male/female in the successful  promotion

Comment: That is your research question, but what are you asking us? We can't answer your research question since we do not have your data.

Comment: I'm assuming your predictor variable is gender and your outcome variable is success/failure. If that is the case perhaps a logistic regression using gender as your predictor would be better than a t-test.

Comment: @user2974951: I am asking whether my approach is valid

Comment: A better option that the t-test might be a two-sample test for equality in proportions.